# ruby on rails identifier error 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Everytime i run this code i get an error can't find what i had did wrong it said something about synatic error tidentifier, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('. Anyone has any suggestion on what it could be?

---

_form.html.haml

```
 = simple_form_for @pin, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    = if @pin.errors.any?
    #errors
    %h2
    = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error")
    prevented this pin from saving
    %ul
    - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li = msg

        .form-group
        = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

        .form-group
        = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

        = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: [From the HAML documentation:](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/) Haml uses __indentation__ to bring the individual elements to represent the HTML structure.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in comments, HAML has to be formatted based on indentation.  So if you have a and if statement then your next line should be indented 2 paces in from the if, and the contents of a div or any other html element will be indented 2 lines from their parent.  Your code should look more like:

```
= simple_form_for @pin, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
  = if @pin.errors.any?
    #errors
      %h2
        = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error")
        prevented this pin from saving
        %ul
          - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li = msg

  .form-group
    = f.input :move_in, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
  .form-group
    = f.input :move_out, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
    = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: oh ok thank you now i get it @trh